# Invalid Selector Exception in Selenium with CSS selectors

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am new to web crawling and I am trying to write a simple script to get course names from a University course catalog table:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

url = 'https://courses.illinois.edu/schedule/2018/fall/CS'
driver.get(url)

course_names = []
for i in range(1, 69):
    if(float(i)%2 != 0): #odd row number
        curr_name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('tr.odd:nth-child(i) > td:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)').text
    else:
        curr_name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('tr.even:nth-child(i) > td:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)').text

    course_names.append(curr_name)
print(course_names)

driver.quit()
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given css selector expression "tr.odd:nth-child(str(i)) > td:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)" is invalid: InvalidSelectorError: 'tr.odd:nth-child(str(i)) > td:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)' is not a valid selector: "tr.odd:nth-child(str(i)) > td:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)"
```

I am completely lost on how to get around this. I am just trying to get it to go through the table. It just does not seem to like i. I know this works:

```
tr.odd:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)
tr.even:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)
tr.odd:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: not exeperienced with selenium but for me `i` is inside the string used as the selector and it's not the variable `i` defined outside which is wrong .... i think you should have something like  `'nth-child('+i+')'`

Comment: It seems your css selectors are incorrect. Did you evaluate those?

Comment: I tried both suggested replacements for i but I am still getting the same error. Any other tips?

Comment: nvm, 'nth-child('+str(i)+')' eventually worked :)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues with your code:

- `i` is used as a character in your selector. Replace with `nth-child(" + str(i) + ")`
- you are filtering the odd and even rows in your script and in the selector. Choose one, not both.
- locating elements and reading the text in a loop is expensive. Scraping the text directly with some JavaScript would be a better approach.

```py
rows = driver.execute_script("""
    return [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('#default-dt tbody tr'), row => [
       row.cells[0].innerText,             /* Course number */
       row.cells[1].innerText,             /* Course title  */
       row.querySelector('[href]').href    /* Course link   */
    ]);
    """)

for code, title, href in rows:
    print(code, title, href)
```

Comment: I tried making the replacement you suggested but it still is giving the same error

Comment: Try the script in the console of your browser (F12) to figure out the issue.

Comment: how is that going to show anything different? I am running script in jupyter notebook. can browser console run python scripts?

Comment: print all the selectors from python and try them in the browser's console with `document.querySelector('tr.odd:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)')`